# Origins of the phrase "spitting nails"

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the phrase "spitting nails"?  I know what it means, but am curious about its origin.  Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please remember that a strong question should be complete— what do you understand the phrase to mean, and what has your preliminary research into its origins suggested so far? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Spit nails  is an AmE variant of the more common methaporic expressions

***[Spit blood/venom](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/spit-blood-venom)***:

(***US also spit nails,***  Australian English also spit tacks):

> - to speak in an angry way, or to show anger:
>   *I thought he was going to spit blood when he saw what had happened.* (Cambridge Dictionary)

The expression is from the '60s:

> - 1965 Sep. 6, Ann Landers, "Exception is Acknowledged," Spokane Daily Chronicle, p. 17 (retrieved 22 Nov 2013):
> - ***[O]ne thing about Aunt Jenny gets me so mad I could spit nails.***

Wiktionary

Comment: Are you sure it has nothing to do with "spitting tacks/nails"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upholstery_hammer